# Is there any way to send SMS to another device using internet?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, sms, internet

Is there any way to send SMS to another device using internet? I don't want to use phone native. I want to use internet to send messages.

I'm not talking about android applications like Viber, WhatsApp Messenger, etc. If we are using those services, other devices we need to send SMS must have installed the same application. But I don't want to do that. If at all, I want to install an app only on my Android device and send SMS to other devices using internet. (other devices means all other devices which can receive SMS -- not only smart phones but also devices like [nokia 1100](http://www.gsmarena.com/nokia_1100-512.php))

Comment: Please note that *Is there an app for X* type questions are off topic here (see our [FAQ]). I took the freedom to re-phrase it to your real issue; guess you'd also accept solutions not involving any 3rd-party-apps :)

Comment: I don't see how this is an Android question.

Comment: off topic. "I'm not talking about android applications..." then how can it be an Android question?

Comment: @William please read whole sentence. "I'm not talking about android applications like Viber, WhatsApp Messenger, etc." i'm talking about android apps, but they are not like Viber, WhatsApp Messenger.

Comment: Use gateway like way2sms.

Answer (score 6):

The only way to accomplish this is to use an online SMS gateway, which means you send the message to the service provider via the internet, and they forward it to the recipient over SMS. There are several service providers for this, but mostly they require a subscription, i.e. they're not free. Just google for "sms gateway" to find them.

Some service providers have Android app support, but this depends on your region and the selected service provider.

Note that most service providers don't allow you to use your own number as the sender, therefore the recipient may have a hard time replying to you.

Comment: yes. agree with you. There are several service providers for this, but mostly they require a subscription. [SMSGlobal](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smsglobal.android.activity) is a example. benefit of this app is we can use any number as sender. but have to pay for their service. but i'm looking for some thing we can send SMS using internet, without paying for the SMS service.

Comment: Ok, that aspect of the question is definitely off topic here, as it has nothing to do with Android.

Comment: Why this question is off topic ? I'm asking for a android app which can send SMS using internet, without paying money for SMS service(except applications like Viber and WhatsApp Messenger which need to installed same app on both device to send and receive SMS). This is not a programming related question.

Comment: Like Izzy commented on your question and mentioned in the [FAQ](http://android.stackexchange.com/faq#what-about-other-android-related-questions), questions like "Can you suggest an app that does X" are off topic. The core of your problem is finding a free SMS gateway, which is not related to Android in any way. When you find a suitable gateway, you can search the [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store) for an app that supports the gateway.

Answer (score 0):

Try way2sms.com. You have to subscribe or create an account with them, but then you can send unlimited messages through their gateway.